# Kendo TabStrip - Item Moves within Strip

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I am using a tabstrip that works fine except for one thing. Sometimes, when I click on an element within the tabstrip, mainly anything to the right of the center, it moves whatever I clicked to the center of the tabstrip. Is there a way to disable this action?

Currently, this tabstrip has about 20 tabs but only 6 show at a time. So I use arrows to navigate back and forth. I can't have the tabstrip readjusting as it messes up the JS.

The main thing I need is if I choose something within the tabstrip, I can't have it move. Only the arrows can make it move.

Comment: can you please share some code examples?

Comment: "I can't have the tabstrip readjusting as it messes up the JS." - address this issue. Such behavior means other bugs can come up in the future.